# Korean-English Toggle Windows 10 does not work in Microsoft Excel

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to type in both Korean and English in Excel (app version on my laptop). I know I can switch the toggle with the right alt key.
However when typing in excel it does not work.

When I hit the alt key, I see that the toggle switches to Hangul. When I want to type a character, nothing appears in the cell. When I type a second character the toggle switches back to English and an letter appears on the screen.

How can I fix the toggle in excel?

Comment: For me, in Office 365 the AltGr doesn't switch the keyboard. Is my setup different from yours?

Comment: It doesnt switch the language of the keyboard itself. But with the Korean keyboard (microsoft IME) there is a toggle to switch from english to korean within the same keyboard.

Comment: Does this switch work only for the keyboard, does Windows know about the switch?

Comment: Yes it works within internet explorer and it also works in microsoft word. It is not something I installed myself.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/Korean/comments/1xxmjb/is_there_anyway_to_set_a_hotkey_to_switch_between/

Comment: Please try going to Windows Settings > Time & Lanuage > Language > click the Korean Language > Options, remove the related keyborad, then add it back to check this issue.